# PowerBI Dax Measure Not Grouping by Day of Week

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables.
I am joining both of them via a 1 to many relationship.
The KPI I want to use is in `Table_1`, but I'm grouping it based on a column in `Table_2`.

When I throw the measure onto PowerBI, it gives the same value for all rows.
I created the measure like this:

```
sales_in_cents := (sum(Table_1[Sales]) * 100)
```

When I group the data using a column from `Table_2`, it gives me the same value for each row in Table_2.

1. Why is this?
2. How do I fix it?

**Edit #1**

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830916/all-rows-and-total-of-the-rows-showing-same-values-in-power-bi), but I do have a relationship.

**Edit #2:**

Table_1 has a 1 to many relationship with Table_2 and cross filter direction is set to single.

**Edit #3:**

I think I need to use some sort of combination of the LookUpValue and/or RelatedValue Function.

Comment: Check your relationship. You have 1 to many with "corss filter direction" set to ?? Which table is filtering which based on your relationship? Probably you need to change this setting.

Comment: Edited my post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Table_1 has a 1 to many relationship with Table_2 and cross filter direction is set to single.

That means  that Table_1 can filter Table_2, but not the other way round. This is why you get repeated values when using a column from Table_2 and a measure based on the Table_1, the filter context doesn't propagate

How to solve it

1. Measure with TREATAS:
   https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/
2. Calculated column in Table_2 that would use RELATED (as each row in Table_2 has a single, related row in Table_1, for referencing the many side you need to use RELATEDTABLE)
3. changing the relationship to bidirectional - it can create ambiguity, so I don't recommend it

This model seems a bit peculiar, is it something like a Table_1 is monthly budgets, while Table_2 is daily sales? In general star schema is recommended in the tabular models, it makes life much easier if you can use that schema